# Why is np.nextafter(0, 1) not equivalent to the float64 epsilon value?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, floating-point

This is very weird!

np.nextafter returns the smallest number after 0. Shouldn't this be equal to the float64 epsilon?

```
In [25]: np.nextafter(0, 1).dtype == np.finfo(np.float64).eps.dtype
Out[25]: True

In [26]: np.nextafter(0, 1) < np.finfo(np.float64).eps
Out[26]: True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The float64 epsilon is computed relative to 1.0.  It is *not* the smallest positive number representable in 64 bit floating point.

To find it using `np.nextafter()`, use `np.nextafter(1, 2) - 1`:

```
In [215]: np.nextafter(1, 2) - 1
Out[215]: 2.220446049250313e-16

In [216]: np.finfo(np.float64).eps
Out[216]: 2.220446049250313e-16
```

Answer (score 1):

A floating-point number is comprised of:

- A sign: + or −.
- Some number *n* of digits in some base *b*, including a decimal or radix point: *d*<sub>0</sub>.*d*<sub>−1</sub>*d*<sub>−2</sub>*d*<sub>−3</sub>…*d*<sub>*−(n*−1)</sub>.
- The base *b* raised to some power *e*: *b*<sup>*e*</sup>.

The sign is applied to the digits, and the result is multiplied by *b*<sup>*e*</sup>, so the entire number is ±*d*<sub>0</sub>.*d*<sub>−1</sub>*d*<sub>−2</sub>*d*<sub>−3</sub>…*d*<sub>*−(n*−1)</sub> • *b*<sup>*e*</sup>. In computing, *b* is often 2, meaning each digit is a bit. In the common IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary floating-point format, *n* is 53.

The so-called machine epsilon is the place value of *d*<sub>*−(n*−1)</sub> when the exponent *e* is 0. In other words, the machine epsilon is +0.000…1 • *b*<sup>0</sup>, which equals *b*<sup>−(*n*−1)</sup>. For the common 64-bit format, this is 2<sup>−52</sup>.

In any floating-point format, there is a least value that *e* is allowed to have (since it must fit into a field of bits reserved for it). For the common 64-bit format, this is −1022. So the smallest positive value a floating-point number in this format can have is +0.000…1 • *2*<sup>−1022</sup>. That equals 2<sup>−52</sup> • 2<sup>−1022</sup> = 2<sup>−1074</sup>.

In other words, the machine epsilon tells you the step size of floating-point numbers near 1. The step size depends on the exponent, so it is greater for greater numbers and smaller for smaller numbers. Near zero, the step size is 2<sup>−1074</sup>.